# How do I set systemwide connection over a proxy server

Tags: linux, debian, proxy

My Internet access is through a proxy, my OS is Debian 8, each application must configure it to use the proxy, but there are some that are a headache to make it work with a proxy, then my question is: is there any way or a program to send all my connections(tcp, udp, etc.) to the proxy? that is to say, how do I set systemwide connection over a proxy server?

Answer (score 18):

There are various solutions for this:

#### 1. Configuring http_proxy variables

You can set `$http_proxy` and other such variables. Most applications will pick this variable automatically. To set it system-wide, you can set this variable in either your `~/.bashrc` file or `/etc/profile`. Set it as:

```
http_proxy=http://user:password@proxyserver.com:3128
https_proxy=https://user:password@proxyserver.com:3128
export http_proxy
export https_proxy
```

#### 2. Using proxy_chains

Some applications would not use your proxy variable and they might not even have settings to use a proxy server. In such a case, you can direct all your PC traffic through a proxy server by using `proxy_chains`.

I've never used `proxy_chains`, however their homepage seems to tell it all in one single page: http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/howto.html

#### 3. Using transparent proxy

To force all your PC connection through a proxy, you can also use transparent proxy as an alternative to proxy_chains. I don't have much idea how to set this up (*I did this a long time back though and it worked!*) so you'll have to look on your own.

Comment: `proxychains` works flawlessly on FreeBSD, it is awesome.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without plaintexting the password?

Answer (score 2):

As shivams said there are various solutions for this.Just by exporting `http_proxy` you can't setup the connection. The way I will do setup the proxy will be as below,

1. First I will setup the authentication by running the `cntlm`.

   a. To do that edit the `/etc/cntlm.conf` file by adding your username,  password(you can also use hash generated for your password), domain, workstation and the proxy etc...

   b. And I will listen to the port 3128.
2. I will setup the proxy for different applications or programs like for `wget` I will setup inside `/etc/wgetrc`, if it is `curl` then in `curlrc` etc...
3. I will export the `http(s)_proxy` with `http://localhost:3128`.You can set this environment variable for a particular session or you can set it putting it inside `/etc/profile.d/`
4. Done

Answer (score 2):

To setup the proxy environment variable as a global variable, open /etc/profile file:

```
# vi /etc/profile
```

Add the following information:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy-server.mycorp.com:3128/
```

OR

```
export http_proxy=http://USERNAME:PASSOWRD@proxy-server.mycorp.com:3128/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set proxy in settings preference and it will reflect everywhere

[image]

Comment: What is the impact of this concretely? What variables / settings are edited? I would like to write a script that does this instead of doing it with the UI.

Comment: @Guillermo According to the available input boxes, I would suppose it is modifying `*_proxy` environmental variables every other answer (for now) has referred to.

Comment: on dconf system like ubuntu 20.04 this is using the `gsettings` client for modifying the settings database of gnome.